# OpenGL for Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, file, opengl

I have Windows 7 installed, and I would like to use OpenGL. So I want to use the opengl32.lib(I wrote DLL before, but it's .lib).

My problem is, this library is in a folder named Windows Kits -> 8.0 or 8.1 but I don't find anything about 7.x. 
Is this a problem, or can I use this opengl32.dll to start developing with OpenGL?

Comment: I highly suggest you not starting with plain OpenGL. OpenGL is mainly a standard and implementations vary heavly. Also the loading of the extensions (including the ones needed for 4.2) are very difficult to load.
Try to use an extension wrapper like glew and a window library (GLFW, SDL or Qt). The opengl object files should come with your driver anyway.
I found glew+glfw to be easy to use.

Comment: @OutOfBound: Even if you use, for example, glew, you'll still have to have a opengl32.lib and dll.

Comment: I followed a tutorial, I use GLM, GLFW and Glew.
It's ok, I believe it's working for now. 
Thanks

Comment: But the implementation (dll files) are hardware specific. They should come with your installed driver.

Comment: Oups! I was so obnubilated by my question that I made a enormous typo here. I was talking about .lib and not .dll... 
Sorry ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are talking about is created whenever you install a Windows SDK or WDK folder.  For example the default folder for WInodows 8 is:

Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\ or Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\

Note: Your operating system does not have to be Windows 8 in order to use the SDK (though Windows 8 features may not workin a backwards compatible way).

In addition, the current version of OpenGL32.dll is compatible with WInodws 7 and 8.
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows

Just to confirm everything is okay with your system, check if your computer has the required prerequisites for the SDK. It looks OS-wise like you will be fine as Windows 7 is among the compatible operating systems.

For the 8.0 library MSDN says:

The Windows SDK requires the following software and hardware on the computer:
One of the following operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 8, or Windows Server 2012
To install the .NET Framework 4.5 Software Development Kit feature, you must install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable package before you install the Windows SDK. You can download the redistributable package from Microsoft Download Center.
10 megabytes (MB) to 1 gigabyte (GB) hard disk space for installation, depending on the features that you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes! perfect! 
Thanks for your explaination it's all clear now! It works fine!
Thanks again!

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch - Glad to hear that its working.  Very happy to help :-)